# An Euler product involving the prime counting function. Does its alternating version converge for $s=1$?

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, euler-product

The classical Euler product $\displaystyle \prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}} \left( \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} \right)$ could be rewritten as:

$$eu_0(s):=\prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^s}}{1-\frac{1}{n^s}}\right)^{\pi(n)}\qquad \qquad \Re(s) > 1$$

where $\pi(n)$ is the prime counting function.

After injecting an alternating "character" as follows:

$$eu_1(s):=\prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1-\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^s}}{1-\frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}}\right)^{\pi(n)}\qquad \qquad \Re(s) > \frac12 ?$$

the domain of convergence seems to get extended and I am particularly interested in the case $s=1$ where numerical evidence suggests that:

$$\prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1-\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)}}{1-\frac{(-1)^n}{n}}\right)^{\pi(n)}=\frac43$$

Curious whether this is provable?

EDIT: Probably just a coincidence, but also:
$$\frac12 \cdot\prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}}{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}\right)^{n}=\frac43$$

Comment: Being very bad in all the areas you tagged (and many other), I just played with the partial products
$$P_p=\prod_{n=2}^{p} \left( \frac{1-\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)}}{1-\frac{(-1)^n}{n}}\right)^{\pi(n)}$$ and *observed* that, for any even value of $p=2k$, $P_{2k}=\frac 43$.

Comment: Partial summation to the series of $\log$